# Modifying Array Giving Back Wrong Output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to numpy and am trying to do some slicing and indexing with arrays. My goal is to take an array, and use slicing and indexing to square the last column, and then subtract the first column from that result. I then want to put the new column back into the old array.

I've been able to figure out how to slice and index the column to get the result I want for the last column. My problem however is that when I try to put it back into my original array, I get the wrong output (as seen below).

```
theNumbers = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])


sliceColumnOne = theNumbers[:,0]
sliceColumnThree = theNumbers[:,3]**2

editColumnThree = sliceColumnThree - sliceColumnOne

newArray = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[editColumnThree]])
print("nums:\n{}".format(newArray))
```

I want the output to be

```
 [[  1   2   3  15]
 [  5   6   7  59]
 [  9  10  11 135]
 [ 13  14  15 243]]
```

However mine becomes:

```
[list([1, 2, 3, 4]) list([5, 6, 7, 8]) list([9, 10, 11, 12])
 list([array([ 15,  59, 135, 243])])]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Remove the square brackets from around `editColumnThree` in the line that creates `newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stack the vectors on top of eachother, use `vstack`:

```
import numpy as np

theNumbers = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
newNumbers = np.vstack(theNumbers)
print(newNumbers)

>>>[[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]
```

But the issue here isn't just that you need to stack these numbers, you are mixing up columns and rows.  You are changing a row instead of a column.  To change the column, update the last element in each row:

```
import numpy as np

theNumbers = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])

LastColumn = theNumbers[:,3]**2
FirstColumn = theNumbers[:,0]
editColumnThree = LastColumn - FirstColumn

for i in range(4):
  theNumbers[i,3] = editColumnThree [i]

print(theNumbers)

>>>[[  1   2   3  15]
 [  5   6   7  59]
 [  9  10  11 135]
 [ 13  14  15 243]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the last numpy array row to the new one "theNumbers[3] = editColumnThree"

Code:

```
import numpy as np
theNumbers = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])

sliceColumnOne = theNumbers[:,0]
sliceColumnThree = theNumbers[:,3]**2
editColumnThree = sliceColumnThree - sliceColumnOne

theNumbers[3] = editColumnThree
print("nums:\n{}".format(theNumbers))
```

Output:

```
[[  1   2   3   4]
 [  5   6   7   8]
 [  9  10  11  12]
 [ 15  59 135 243]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newArray = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[editColumnThree]])
print("nums:\n{}".format(newArray))
```

this way, `editColumnThree` is the last **row**, not column. You can use

```
newArray = theNumbers.copy() # if a copy is needed
newArray[:,-1] = editColumnThree # replace last (-1) column
```